# Using article "the" before specific software package names

Tags: grammar, articles, names

We have developed some software packages: "pythonmaths package", "pythonsets package" etc. We are writing an article about these developed packages. Here are our queries.

1. The article contains sections on each of these packages. Can we use "The pythonmaths package", "The pythonsets package" as titles of sections or should we use  "pythonmaths package", "pythonsets package" as titles of sections in the article.
2. Can we use "The pythonmaths package", "The pythonsets package" throughout the article or should we use "pythonmaths package", "pythonsets package"?

Comment: "The X package" if you must refer to it as a package. If not, then just "X", without "the" *or* "package".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use an article.

Perhaps you are wondering this because titles of things like software, movies, games etc don't usually need articles as they are proper nouns.

For example:

- I watched *Batman*.
- I play *Minecraft*.
- I installed *Pythonmaths*.

However, 'package' is a common noun, and these require articles, eg "*a package*". But you want to refer to a *specific* package, which is why you are using the definite article. And you are prefixing it with the proper noun of your software to act as an adjective and identify it.

For example:

- I watched **the** *Batman* trailer.
- I installed **the** *Minecraft* update.
- I downloaded **the** *Pythonmaths* package.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it okay if I  use "pythonmaths package" as a title of section instead of using "The pythonmaths package"?

Comment: @user61681 Without an article it will sound like a proper compound noun. Is that what you want? Look at my second set of examples and ask yourself if you think it would be normal to see a title of a section named any of those things without an article.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.